# Quiz with score system in actionscript 2.0 adobe CS6

Tags: flash, adobe, actionscript-2, flash-cs6

I'm trying to make a simple quiz in cs6 with actionscript 2.0. Basically there are 8 questions and each question has 3 possible answers. For each answer I want to assign a different score. Depending on the total score, a different text is displayed at the end of the quiz. What is the best/easiest way to code this?
Graphically-wise, the quiz is as good as finished (as it's pretty basic) and I already have programmed the actions of clicking the 3 possible answer buttons and the start button etc. 
I only don't know how to make this score system.
I found someone who already asked my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748711/flash-as2-quiz-with-individual-points-for-each-answer) but he didn't really get much of an answer nor did I understand his code.
Can somebody please help me out? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

I added this to one of the buttons in the beginning:

```
on (release) {
_global.score=0;
_global.score=_global.score+x;
```

}

At the last couple questions I added this script (it's supposed to view a template with the result of the quiz based on the total score):

```
on (release) {
if (score<=x) {
    gotoandstop(y);
} else if (score=x or x or x or x) {
    gotoandstop(y);
} else if (score>=x) {
    gotoandstop(y);  
} else {
    gotoandplay(y);
}
```

I replaced the actual numbers with x and y because you obviously can't know how I organized the templates.
But somehow in the last script the total score calculation doesn't give the correct result...

Answer (score 0):

Create a counter and then add a different value when clicking on a certain button.

Creating a counter:

```
_global.score=0; //Global makes it so that you can ccess it from different frames.
```

Add this code to one of the buttons:

```
on (release) {
    _global.score= _global.score+1; //Instead of 1 you can add any value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've figured it out.
I put _global.score = 0 on the first frame and on the first couple buttons I put this:

```
on (release) {
gotoAndplay(x);
}
on (release) { 
_global.score = _global.score + x; 
}
```

Then at the very last question I put this code at each button:

```
}
on (release) { 
if (_global.score <= x) 
{ 
    gotoAndStop(11); 
} 
else if (_global.score == x || _global.score == x || _global.score == x || score == x) 
{ 
    gotoAndStop(x); 
} 
else if (_global.score >=x)
{ 
    gotoAndPlay(x); 
} 
else
    gotoAndplay(x);
}
```